# Specified cast is not valid, getting all values from jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

Specified cast is not valid, please tell me any way to get max/min value from all the values stored in array, not from the specific index.

```
int max = jArray.Cast<int>().Max(); 
                System.Console.Write("\n\n Max marks:" + max );
```

Declaration of jagged array:

```
 string TotalStudents;

        System.Console.Write("Enter the Total No. Of Students:");
        TotalStudents = Console.ReadLine();

        int value;
        bool result = int.TryParse(TotalStudents, out value);

        JaggedArray jag = new JaggedArray(value);

        int[][] jArray = new int[jag.noOfStudents][];



        for (int i = 0; i < jag.noOfStudents; i++)
        {


            System.Console.Write("Enter the Total No. Of Subjects of Student:" + i + ":\t");
            string TotalSubjects = Console.ReadLine();

            int Subjectvalue;
            bool Sresult = int.TryParse(TotalSubjects, out Subjectvalue);
            jArray[i] = new int[Subjectvalue];

            for (int a = 0; a < Subjectvalue; a++)
            {
                System.Console.Write("\nEnter the marks obtained of subject:" + a + " of student " + i + ":\t");
                string TotalMarks = Console.ReadLine();

                int Marksvalue;
                bool Mresult = int.TryParse(TotalMarks, out Marksvalue);
                jArray[i][a] = Marksvalue;

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JArray` is a jagged array(Array of Arrays), that's why specific cast to `int` is invalid.

I would suggest flatten the structure using `SelectMany` and look for `Max`.

```
int max = jArray.SelectMany(x=>x.ToArray()).Max();
```